# How Do We Configure Autofill Services in O Developer Preview 2?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

In O Developer Preview 1, to configure what autofill service the device should use (e.g., the one that you are writing), you would go into Settings > Apps & notifications > Default apps > Autofill app. Tapping on that entry would bring up a list dialog to choose the autofill app to use.

However, in O Developer Preview 2, there is no "Autofill app" entry in that screen, at least on a Nexus 5X and the x86 emulator:

[image: Default Apps Screen in ODP2 Settings]

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/autofill.html#prerequisites), though, still refers to how we did it in ODP1.

I filed [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38499661), but in the meantime... is there another way to configure an autofill service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It dawned on me when writing the question what Google might have done... and it's just what they did.

Autofill is now configured in Settings > System > Languages & input > Advanced:

[image: Languages & Input Settings in ODP2]